# Change input type datetime-local picker UI minute steps

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change steps on input type `datetime-local` picker UI to show minute steps like 00,15,30 ....
so user cannot pick values like 13, 12, ... from picker UI.

is there any using which picker UI can be changed.

thanks.